# My website doesn't display correctly on some mobile device

Tags: next.js, mobile, responsive

I have developed website for classroom management tatugacamp.com/classroom
I have got feedback from some teacher about thier student's mobile displaying my website like this
Most of them is Android
[image: example picture]

**About my website**
I have deployed my website on Netlify
and frameworks for client-side

- Nextjs: ^12.2.5

I have no idea why this happen, it works well on every mobile that I actully see by myself.
But those feedback I never seen by myself just only picture from teacher who send that to me.

I wonder whether is this my mistake or bug in my website or it just user's mobile fault